# EXCEPT considering DateTime?

Tags: sql, sql-server, set, boolean-logic, inventory-management

I have a database that tracks the location of widgets (i.e. an inventory system that tracks individual items rather than simply Counts of SKUs).

There are two tables concerned:

```
 InventoryUpdates (
     UpdateId   bigint PRIMARY KEY,
     LocationId bigint,
     Type       tinyint, -- an enum column
     DateTime   datetimoffset
 )

 WidgetState {
     SerialNumber varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY,
     UpdateId     bigint
 }
```

#### Explanation:

Inventory Updates are either "Complete", "Additive", or "Subtractive" (this is determined by the `Type` column). When an Update is `Complete`, it means the associated set of `WidgetState` represents the entire inventory (i.e. if a widget is listed, then it's there; and absence of a widget is positive verification that it was not present in the inventory at that time). When an Update is `Additive`, it means the Inventory needs to be determined by summing up all of the subsequent `Additive`updates since the last `Complete` update (just like incremental backups), finally a `Subtractive` update means those items included in the update should be excluded from the inventory. Of course, multiple `Additive` and `Subtractive` updates can appear after a `Complete` update.

So my problem is:

"Given the last `Complete` update and the set of all subsequent `Additive` and `Subtractive` updates, get the current inventory of a location"

The data would look like this:

```
InventoryUpdates
----------------------------------------------
UpdateId   LocationId  Type         DateTime
1          1           Complete     2014-01-01
2          1           Additive     2014-01-02
3          1           Subtractive  2014-01-03
4          1           Additive     2014-01-04

WidgetState
----------------------------------------------
SerialNumber  UpdateId
0001          1
0004          1
008B          2
0001          3
0004          3
0004          4
```

In this simple example, we see that the unique widget `0004` is known to be in the inventory in Update 1, then it's removed in Update 3, then added back in Update 4.

Supposing I want to find out the current inventory, my resultset should be:

```
WidgetsInInventory
----------------------------------------------
SerialNumber
0004
008B
```

There's probably a really simple solution, I just can't think of it right now. I'm thinking it might look something like this:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT SerialNumber,
    Type 
FROM
    WidgetState
    INNER JOIN InventoryUpdates ON WidgetState.UpdateId = InventoryUpdates.UpdateId
WHERE
    InventoryUpdates.Type = Complete OR
    InventoryUpdates.Type = Additive
ORDER BY
    InventoryUpdates.DateTime DESC

EXCEPT

SELECT
    DISTINCT SerialNumber,
    Type 
FROM
    WidgetState
    INNER JOIN InventoryUpdates ON WidgetState.UpdateId = InventoryUpdates.UpdateId
WHERE
    InventoryUpdates.Type = Subtractive
ORDER BY
    InventoryUpdates.DateTime DESC
```

...but then it falls apart when a Subtraction happens regardless of the fact it might have happened with an earlier DateTime value than a subsequent Addition.

#### Update

I just had a thought while on my way home that this might be a solution that works, I'll test it out tomorrow.

The code below uses `DISTINCT` combined with `ORDER BY` to get the *last appearance* of each `WidgetState`, so if the last appearance was an `Addition` then it would cancel-out any previous `Subtraction`, and vice-versa (well, if the last appearance was a `Subtraction` then it can then be easily excluded from future super-queries with a `WHERE Type <> Subtractive` predicate). It's just gone 03:00h and I haven't had a chance to try it, but does the theory sound right? Thanks!

```
SELECT
    WidgetState.SerialNumber,
    InventoryUpdates.Type
FROM
    WidgetState
    INNER JOIN InventoryUpdates ON WidgetState.UpdateId = InventoryUpdates.UpdateId
WHERE
    InventoryUpdates.DateTime >= @dateTimeOfLastCompleteUpdate
    AND
    InventoryUpdates.LocationId >= @locationId
GROUP BY
    SerialNumber
ORDER BY
    InventoryUpdates.DateTime DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and found out about `LAST_VALUE` in conjunction with `OVER ... PARTITION BY`, however `LAST_VALUE` is only supported on SQL Server 2012. I'm using 2008 R2, so I needed to find something equivalent.

Fortunately there is: You can add `ROW_NUMBER` to a `PARTITION` and then select the top value (`WHERE rowNumber = 1`) when ordered correctly, so here is my final query:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        WidgetStates.TId,
        InventoryUpdates.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY WidgetStates.Tid ORDER BY InventoryUpdates.DateTime DESC) AS RowN
    FROM
        WidgetStates
        INNER JOIN InventoryUpdates ON WidgetStates.UpdateId = InventoryUpdates.UpdateId
    WHERE
        InventoryUpdates.DateTime >= @lastCompleteUpdateDateTime
        AND
        InventoryUpdates.LocationId = @locationId
    ) As Results
WHERE
    Results.RowN = 1
    AND
    Results.Type >= 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I would approach it differently. Simply counting the widgets. Put -1 if update is Subtractive and 1 for Complete and Additive. Then simply sum the flags and filter those with no-zero (positive) sum.

```
declare @dateTimeOfLastCompleteUpdate Date = '20140101'
declare @locationId int  = 1
;
with cte1 as
(
  select
    ws.SerialNumber,
    ws.UpdateId,
    CASE WHEN iu.Type = 'Subtractive' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END as Flag
  from 
    InventoryUpdates iu
    inner join WidgetState ws
      on ws.UpdateId = iu.UpdateId
  where
    iu.[DateTime] >= @dateTimeOfLastCompleteUpdate
    and iu.LocationId = @locationId
)
, cte2 as
(
  select
    SerialNumber,
    Flag,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by SerialNumber order by UpdateId) as rn
  from
    cte1
)
, cte3 as
(
  select
    SerialNumber,
    sum(flag) as WidgetCount
  from 
    cte2 a
  where
    not exists 
    (
      select * 
      from cte2 b 
      where b.serialnumber = a.serialnumber
      and b.rn = a.rn - 1
      and b.flag = a.flag
    )
  group by
    SerialNumber
)
select SerialNumber from cte3 where WidgetCount = 1
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ebf95/12/0).

Comment: A problem with your approach is that it is not allow subsequent duplicate updates to be idempotent. If there are two consecutive Subtractive updates that claim the same serial number `X` was removed, then a subsequent Additive update claiming that `X` was restocked would be hidden because its `+1` would be buried by the two `-1`s.

Comment: I changed the solution to prevent more than one update in the same direction in a row. It's more complicated, but works.